# how to redirect output of ssh to a file

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I want to make ssh connection to my server but I don't want to enter password. I want to save output to a file like so:

```
$ ssh root@x.x.x.x -p 22 1>output 2>&1
```

but when I run it the output is shown to me:

```
root@x.x.x.x's password:
```

I want this state redirect to a file and not show to me then close ssh connection immediately...

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You've not done anything wrong, it's just that the password entry is special.

`ssh` assumes that you don't want password entry to get in the way of whatever you *really* wanted to pipe, so it uses `/dev/tty` for the password prompt, instead of `stdout`.

You can tell `ssh` to not ask for passwords like this:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes root@x.x.x.x
```

It will now just exit, if there's no key or existing connection that works.

I don't think there's a straight-forward way to capture the "password: " prompt text though.

Comment: So... What should I do to solve it?

Comment: I was just looking that up; edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a password.  Use a public-private key with a null passphrase.
ssh -2 -I /home/localloginame/.ssh/astroboy   -l yourlogin hostname \
  "cd inbox; ls -l; exit"

What's this astroboy?  It's a file.   It's a private key.  When making a key, you end up with a 
private part: /home/localloginname/.ssh/astroboy and a 
public part:  /home/localloginname/.ssh/astroboy.pub

Now how to make that key....  /????/ssh/bin/key-gen -t dsa astroboy

Then it asks for a passphrase.  You can put in a null passphrase.  It will complain, but keep going.  Then you have it.

I would hope if I am telling you wrong someone will correct me.